# Radio button value not updating in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have 4 radio buttons in my form:

```
<tr><td>Type</td><td>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="a" value="a" >A
<input type="radio" name="type" id="b" value="b" >B
<input type="radio" name="type" id="c" value="c" >C
<input type="radio" name="type" id="d" value="d" >D</td></tr>
```

On page load I set one of the radio buttons using jquery

```
$("#b").prop("checked", true);
```

Now I select the value d in my form and submit. In PHP I echo $_POST['type'] , I am always getting the value which was set during page load using jquery i.e. in this case b instead of d.

Why is the value not updating?

Thanks.

UPDATE:Thanks all, it was due to unintentional val() called on radio button. So if radio button value is set using val() it will not change later, strange behavior.

Comment: But that is during load and then I click and set the radio button value as d before form submit

Comment: in that case when there's a submit action change the page load value into `d` (or whatever was selected before submit) instead of the default `b`.

Comment: Does some other part of your code select the `b option` as well?

Comment: @tradyblix do I need to manually set the selected radio button using jquery after the user clicks a radio button

Comment: @tastro no ,  it is selected only once

Comment: Thanks all, it was due to unintentional val() called on radio button. So if radio button value is set using val() it will not change later, strange behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery 1.6+

```
$('#b').prop('checked', true);
$('#b').prop('checked', false);
```

jQuery 1.5 and below

```
$('#b').attr('checked','checked');
$('#b').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: Do I need to remove the checked attribute manually if the user clicks on some other radio button ?

Comment: No you don't have to. The buttons are grouped by name='type'.

Comment: Thanks it was due unintentional val() called on radio button, not sure about -1, upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using

```
$("#b").prop("checked", true);
```

why dont you write your radio buttons as

```
<input type="radio" name="type" id="a" value="a" >A
<input type="radio" name="type" id="b" value="b" checked="checked"  >B
<input type="radio" name="type" id="c" value="c" >C
<input type="radio" name="type" id="d" value="d" >D
```

Comment: because I am making an ajax call [when user enters first field in form] to determine which radio button needs to be selected. It is an update page where once the user enters his id in the first field of form rest of his details are populated in the form to be edited and submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Works like a charm ;-)).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" /></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#b').attr('checked', 'checked');
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sbmt']) && isset($_POST['type'])) {
?>
        <h1>Selected type: <?php echo($_POST['type']); ?></h1>
<?php
}
?>

        <form action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="radio" name="type" id="a" value="a" /> A</li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="type" id="b" value="b" /> B</li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="type" id="c" value="c" /> C</li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="type" id="d" value="d" /> D</li>
            </ul>

            <input name="sbmt" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, it works correctly, but not working in my case, maybe it has something to do with setting the radio button value in ajax call.

Comment: @ak111in Can you show more of your code? Is your browser correctly updating the selection of the radio?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['sb']))
{
    echo $_REQUEST['type'];
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#b').attr('checked','checked');
});
</script>
<tr><td>Type</td><td>
<form name="frm" method="post" action="">
<input type="radio" name="type" id="a" value="a" >A
<input type="radio" name="type" id="b" value="b" >B
<input type="radio" name="type" id="c" value="c" >C
<input type="radio" name="type" id="d" value="d" >D</td></tr>
<input type="submit" name="sb" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
 $("#b").attr("checked", true);
```

or

```
     $("#b").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Comment: does not make any difference